# Android - selecting new input, scrolls back to previous input selected if type=text

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

If I have many input elements in a table, such that they go off screen, I get weird behavior in Android when switching between elements of `type='text'`.

Specifically, if I select an input of `type='text'` and then scroll to a different one of `type='text'`, such that the first one is no longer on screen, and select that different one it always scrolls back to the previous selected.  In addition, it sometimes does an sometimes doesn't ultimately select the different input - otherwise it just deselects the first (after scrolling to it).

This behavior doesn't occur when switching between elements of `type='number'`.  Any thoughts on what is going on here?  Any thoughts on how to make switching between inputs of `type='text'` like switching between inputs of `type='number'`?

I am guessing it has something to do with the soft keyboard or the suggestions it displays for inputs of `type='text'`.

You can play with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud27rjsd/2/) which has one row of inputs of `type='text'` and one row of inputs of `type='number'`

Test device is a 2014 Moto X running Android L.